# Cannot import google io source code 2011

Tags: android

I am new to android development . I'm  trying to download and run the 
iosched 2011 source code for HoneyComb. And, I looked in most of the forums, and not been able to understand what to do . So, if anyone of u guys could give a step by step process for downloading and running on eclipse locally , I would be very greatful.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for specific questions, not tutorials. Please read the [FAQ].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to import the code into Eclipse, try out this link:
http://code.google.com/p/iosched/issues/detail?id=18

> Download Eclipse
>
> Download and install Mercurial Plugin
>   (http://www.javaforge.com/project/HGE)
>
> Download and install Android
>   SDK
>
> Eclipse : Import -> Mercurial -> Clone using existing Mercurial
>   repository -> (your local mercurial repository)
>
> Eclipse : 'Disable' Project -> Build Automatically
>
> Eclipse : New -> Android Project -> 'check' Project from existing
>   source -> Browse -> 'local repository' iosched ~> android -> done
>
> "Project name is actually HomeActivity" - can change during project
>   creation
>
> Eclipse : Project right click -> Build Project
>
> "Huge number of errors"
>
> Eclipse : Project right click -> Android Tools -> Add Compatibility
>   Libraries
>
> "Will see some things going on on Console Window" (internet connection
>   required)
>
> Eclipse : Project right click -> Build Project
>
> "Possibly 6 errors" - errors due to Google Analytics lib not included
>   in build path
>
> Download Google Analytics SDK from
>   http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/download.html
>
> Eclipse : Configure Build path by including libGoogleAnalytics.jar
>
> Eclipse : Project right click -> Build Project
>
> Run iosched ...........